# Can I tell if someone copied files and folders from my computer to a usb or to the network?

Tags: windows-8

Can I tell if someone copied files and folders from my computer to a usb or to the network ? I'm working on windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Windows records a last-accessed date for files;  a copy would typically modify the access date.

From a command line, this is

```
DIR *.* /T:A
```

or similar (modify the file specifier to whatever you want to view.)

You can also display the last-accessed date from Windows explorer by turning on that column -- my screenshot is Win7 but similar is possible in Windows 8:
[image]